# Indexing 80 million documents to elasticsearch from Django

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am using the latest version of django elasticsearch dsl and I am using the following command to index around 80 million documents:

```
python manage.py search_index --rebuild --models <model> --parallel
```

However, my system can't handle it and crashes at about 12gb of ram usage. CPU usage is 10% and seems to be fine.

Is there a way to index this amount of django entries to elasticsearch safely?

I found that it is a problem with parallel bulk:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/1101

I tried using the suggestion from the comments by turning the implementation from [django elasticsearch dsl](https://github.com/django-es/django-elasticsearch-dsl/blob/100759875a1eb6b6763587b60927c1f54fef95cb/django_elasticsearch_dsl/documents.py#L177) for parallel bulk to the following:

```
def parallel_bulk(self, actions, **kwargs):
    if self.django.queryset_pagination and 'chunk_size' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['chunk_size'] = self.django.queryset_pagination

    for response in streaming_bulk(client=self._get_connection(), actions=actions, **kwargs):
        pass

    # bulk_actions = streaming_bulk(client=self._get_connection(), actions=actions, **kwargs)
    # As the `parallel_bulk` is lazy, we need to get it into `deque` to run it instantly
    # See https://discuss.elastic.co/t/helpers-parallel-bulk-in-python-not-working/39498/2
    # deque(bulk_actions, maxlen=0)
    # Fake return value to emulate bulk() since we don't have a result yet,
    # the result is currently not used upstream anyway.
    return (1, [])
```

However, when running this code. It seems to fill my memory at [this line](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/8d10e1545e2572d3ab1e92cfaf0968085145eb4d/elasticsearch/helpers/actions.py#L232), which calls this code in django:

```
def _iterator(self, use_chunked_fetch, chunk_size):
    yield from self._iterable_class(self, chunked_fetch=use_chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
```

After this line the memory of my entire system is used (About 12gb ram) and the system crashes. The system crashes before a single document is indexed.

Comment: this seems like bad design of django-elasticsearch-dsl... it looks like they try to load the full result set into memory here: https://github.com/django-es/django-elasticsearch-dsl/blob/master/django_elasticsearch_dsl/registries.py#L157 (I don't know why they do it, but wrapping everything in `set(...)` seems unnecessary to me) No idea if there is another library that doesn't do that, or maybe you can copy and modify some of their code

Comment: I tried dividing the queryset into chunks with slicing, but that didn't seem to work. I'll try looking at this `set(...)` code though. Maybe I can do something with that.

Comment: I seem to have found the issue, but I don't know how to solve it.